# Mysql server update query

Tags: mysql

i have a problem with a a php/mysql based application, its a point of sale system. The problem is a page which is supposed to perform some queries, three of which are inserts to different tables within the database and one update on a table named products..the logic here is updating the products quantity once the business proprietor adds stock. for some weird reason this update always fails but the other queries seem to be working just fine. This problem started after the system  was in use after three months... I tried uninstalling PhpMyadmin and installing a new one but the problem is still there... what can i do??

Comment: You are going to have to give more.

Comment: you need to mention briefly with the code about your problem

Comment: Maybe it is timing out?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you need more debug information for your failed query.
The initial approach could be printing out the query itself and printing it's error output. This may look like:

```
...
$mysqli->query($sql);
echo $sql;
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
...
```

Please update/edit your question with these details, so it would be easier to help you.